# How to retrieve the posted parameters at server side?

Tags: asp.net, rest, httpclient, httprequest

I am trying to implement a RESTful web API on ASP.Net.
To test this Web API I created a small client application, which uses HttpClient.PostAsync.
I add some parameters in a HttpContent object, but whatever I try, I cannot find these posted parameters at server side in my Web API.

Code at client side:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "test", LastName = "test" };

MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Customer>(customer, jsonFormatter);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(base_url, content);
```

Code at server side:

```
string httpMethod = Request.HttpMethod;

if (httpMethod == "POST")
{
    string firstName = Request.QueryString["FirstName"];
    string lastName = Request.QueryString["LastName"];
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at server side I see that Request.AcceptTypes is equal to "application/json", so probably the formatting type was received at server side.
However, Request.QueryString is empty all the time and I don't know how to retrieve the posted parameters...

Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful link which helped me out:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

That works!